# CoordinatorLayout.Behavior: how to set it programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, android-5.0-lollipop, android-coordinatorlayout

I implemented a `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` for my custom view.
When I decorate my view with `app:layout_behavior` and pass it my behavior, it works good.

Now I want to add my view dynamically to the `CoordinatorLayout` and apply the behavior as well, but I did not find a way to apply it.

EDIT:
I found this [website](http://andydyer.org/blog/2015/06/28/using-a-third-party-fab-with-coordinatorlayout/) on how to use a a third-party fab with the coordinator layout. The [implementation](https://github.com/abdyer/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/design/widget/SupportFloatingActionsMenu.java) shows the usage of `@CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior`. When I try to use it in my Xamarin code, `CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehaviour' is an interface. How can I adapt that code?

Answer (score 2):

`CoordinatorLayout`, like most ViewGroups, has its own [`LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.html) class. This class contains all of the data that you can pass in with `layout_` attributes in XML.

Specifically, you are looking for [`CoordinateLayout.LayoutParams#setBehavior()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.html#setBehavior(android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.Behavior)).

Comment: It is not the behaviour of the `CoordinatorLayout.Layout`, but a control that is added to it.